# Anyone had any success developing CUDA programs for NVIDIA shield?

Tags: mobile, cuda, gpu, nvidia

Has anyone managed to get a CUDA program to work on the NVidia shield? In particular getting the wonderful NVidia profiling tools to work?

Comment: Nvidia shield SoC is based on Tegra 4. Tegra K1 is the first Tegra processor you can write CUDA programs for. So you can expect it's not possible to have CUDA programs working on Nvidia shield.

Comment: @Farzad if you provide that as an answer, I would upvote it (keeping in mind the statement is correct for the current shield product).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nvidia shield SoC is based on [Tegra 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegra_4#Tegra_4). [Tegra K1](http://www.nvidia.com/object/tegra-k1-processor.html) is the first Tegra processor you can write CUDA programs for. So you can expect it's not possible to have CUDA programs working on (current) Nvidia shield.

Comment: Will it be possible to deploy to the machine? At TK1 we were installing some toolkits and being able to ssh into the machine etc.